# Regroup pandas column into 2D list based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a pandas dataset with a column of words and a column of integer (0,1).  All words that appear between a zero (first integer, or after a 1) and a 1(including) should be put into a 2D array.

Let me explain:

Consider this pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Text','Selection_Values'])
df["Text"] = ["Hi", "this is", "just", "a", "single", "sentence.", "This", "is another one."]
df["Selection_Values"] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
print(df)
```

This is the example dataset:

```
              Text  Selection_Values
0               Hi                 0
1          this is                 0
2             just                 0
3                a                 0
4           single                 0
5        sentence.                 1
6             This                 0
7  is another one.                 1
```

The expected result should be:

```
[["Hi this is just a single sentence."],["This is another one"]]
```

**Do you have any idea of how to go about this ?**

This is what I have done so far:

```
result = []

s = ""
for i in range(len(df["Text"])):
    s += df["Text"][i] + " "
    if df["Selection_Values"][i] == 1:
        result.append([s])
        s = ""
```

It works:

```
[['Hi this is just a single sentence. '], ['This is another one. ']]
```

...but it might not be the best method. It does not make use of the pandas framework at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `numpy.split` + `Series.str.cat` one-liner:

```
In [143]: [[s.str.cat(sep=' ')] for s in np.split(df.Text, df[df.Selection_Values == 1].index+1) if not s.empty]                               
Out[143]: [['Hi this is just a single sentence.'], ['This is another one.']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Really cool, one liner! 
I realized that the last sentence of the dataset might have no closing 1. How would you handle this ?

Comment: @henry, it will also work for series `df["Selection_Values"] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]` (last `0`)

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Using `shift` + `' '.join`.  This assumes of course that every sentence has a closing `1` and there are no hanging sentences.

---

```
g = df['Selection_Values'].shift().eq(1).cumsum()

df['Text'].groupby(g).agg(' '.join).tolist()
```

```
['Hi this is just a single sentence.', 'This is another one.']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I realized that the last sentence of the dataset might have no closing `1`. How would you handle this ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible way:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Text', 'Selection_Values'])
df["Text"] = ["Hi", "this is", "just", "a", "single", "sentence.", "This", "is another one."]
df["Selection_Values"] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

# Add column with an unique group ID for each sentence
df['group_id'] = df.Selection_Values.shift(1, fill_value=0).cumsum()

# Join the strings that have the same group ID
sentence_series = df.groupby('group_id')['Text'].agg(' '.join)

# Optional: convert result series to list
sentence_list = sentence_series.to_list()

print(sentence_list)
# Output:
# ['Hi this is just a single sentence.', 'This is another one.']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !  I realized that the last sentence of the dataset might have no closing 1. How would you handle this ?

Comment: @henry The code solution should also work this case (since the last value of `df.Selection_Values` is discarded anyway by the `shift` operation).